# Задание размера изображения в миллиметрах

Tags: winforms, c#

Подскажите, как можно задать размер изображения в WinForms в миллиметрах?

Необходимо для того, чтобы изображение сохраняло размер в независимости от размеров и разрешения экрана. Вариант с определенным процентом от площади экрана не подходит.

Comment: А при чем тут миллиметры тогда?
Разрешение экрана всегда в пикселах, и процентное соотношение всегда работает правильно. Что у вас с ними не получается?
Смотрите в сторону настроек монитора, где указано, сколько точек на дюйм, переводите в миллиметры и получайте свои значения.

Comment: Как вы это себе представляете?) компьютер достает линейку и замеряет сколько у вас там миллиметров на экране занимает изображение и подгоняет размер?)

Comment: @Сергей, в общем-то в этом есть небольшой смысл. Например картинка может по разному смотреться на телевизоре 1920*1080 но диагональю 40 дюймов, и на мониторе с тем же разрешением, только с диагональю 22 дюйма.
Хотя я себе это слабо представляю. Но при этом можно запросто это сделать, правда не знаю как сие сделать в csharp.

Comment: Я бы не ставил такое убийственное разрешение на 40 дюймовом монике. Да и я в принципе не могу представить острую необходимость соответствия размера изображения на экране в миллиметрах.

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подумайте насчет этого:

1. Получаем разрешение экрана (1280 * 800)
2. Получаем количество пикселов на дюйм (96dpi = 3.779dpmm) (соответственно реальный размер монитора в миллиметрах = (1280/3.779 = 338.71) на (800/3.779 = 211.69) (33.8 * 21.1 см)
3. Теперь мы знаем, размер изображения, предположим, 200 * 200
4. Также получим на нашем экране 52.92 * 52.92
5. Получите проценты от полученных значений 15.65% * 25.08% и примените их к пикселам (хотя не уверен, можете другим способом вернуться к пикселам)

А теперь давайте посмотрим сюда: 200/(1280/100) = 15,625% на 200/(800/100) = 25%. Невероятно, не правда ли? Только если вспомнить, что есть такая штука, которая называется "погрешность вычислений" и, знаете ли вы, какую погрешность даст 5 операций деления вместо двух?

Правда если вчитаться в ваш вопрос, тогда вот такое действо намечается:

1. Определите константу, которая определяет "идеальный" монитор, т.е. на котором ваша картинка идеальных размеров (описывающая размеры)
2. Определите реальный размер картинки на другом экране
3. Теперь вычислите, нужно ли ее уменьшить или увеличить, относительно идеального монитора

Как-то так. Можете вносить поправки, это первое что приходит в голову. Теперь стоит формализировать, как вычислять значение "идеального монитора" вместо константы, но пока в голову ничего не лезет.

Answer (score 0):

[вики](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)
просвящайтесь :)

ps: dex всё правильно говорит в коментарии к вопросу.

pss: если дело касается принтера, то там кажись можно самуму выставлять PPI,
ну и делать соответсвующие вычисления