# Физический размер монитора

Tags: delphi

Как программно определить физический размер активного монитора (ширина, длина или хотя бы диагональ), в сантиметрах или миллиметрах или в дюймах. Например, как это делает программа эверест.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуете функцию [GetDeviceCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28VS.85%29.aspx) из Windows API, которая с параметрами HORZSIZE и VERTSIZE возвращает физические размерности требуемого экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Помойму как то так

```
.....
var DC:HDC;
    w,h:integer;
    g:real;

.....

 DC:=GetDC(0);//Получаем HDC активного монитора
 h:=GetDeviceCaps(DC,HORZSIZE);//Возвращает ширину экрана в милиметрах
 w:=GetDeviceCaps(DC,VERTSIZE);//Возвращает высоту экрана в милиметрах
 g:=sqrt(sqr(w)+sqr(h))/25.4;//Получаем диагональ
```

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите на мой ответ в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10469/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: У меня 2 ноутбука, у одного диагональ 15,4 дюйма, у другого 14 дюймов. Разрешение у ОБОИХ 1280*800 пикселей, PixelsPerInch у ОБОИХ возвращает 96. Несмотря на то что физические размеры обоих мониторов разные. Есть например вариант нахождения размера этих мониторов через EDID (21 и 22 байт), но встает вопрос о нахождении пути к нужному EDID, т.к неизвестен ID активного монитора. Пробовал этот ID находить через WMI, но почему то код работает не на всех компьютерах. Вот и обращаюсь сюда за помощью.